# Change Lowest frame dynamically

Tags: html, frames

I have a page with 3 frames, top, middle, and bottom that display a different page in each frame.  I'd like to change what is third frame when I click a button on the middle frame.

Main Page:

```
<html>
<frameset rows="475,6%,*">
  <frame name="top" scrolling="no" noresize target="middle" src="top.htm">
  <frame name="middle" src="middle.htm" scrolling="no" noresize>
  <frame name="bottom" src="bottom.htm" scrolling="no" noresize>
  <noframes>
  <body>

  <p>This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.</p>

  </body>
  </noframes>
</frameset>
```

What I'd to do is setup a button in the middle.htm page so that when it is clicked the bottom frame will now display a different page.

Any idea how to set this up?

TIA

BR

Comment: Via javascript? `top.frames['bottom'].location.href='otherpagehere.htm';` Via a link? `<a href="otherpagehere.htm" target="bottom">Link</a>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `top.document.getElementsByName( "bottom" )[ 0 ].src = "YOUR_NEW_PAGE"`

Comment: Prefix `document` by `top.` (because the code is called from within the frame), and replace your wrongly spelled method with the correct one. The final result: `top.document.getElementsByName("bottom")[0].src="YOUR_NEW_PAGE";`

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend using frames, but you can try this:

```
<script>
function changePage(strPage)
{
parent.middle.location.href = strPage; 
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="changePage('page1.htm')">Page 1</a>   
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="changePage('page2.htm')">Page 2</a>   
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="changePage('page3.htm')">Page 3</a>   
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="changePage('body.htm')">Home</a>
```